# convert text to PDF using python

Tags: python

I have a problem, I want to run this code but have this error

```py
File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/pdfff.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fpdf import FPDF
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fpdf'
```

I tried this command: `pip install fpdf`, but nothing has changed.

This is the code:

```py
from fpdf import FPDF 

# save FPDF() class into  
# a variable pdf 
pdf = FPDF()    

# Add a page 
pdf.add_page() 

# set style and size of font  
# that you want in the pdf 
pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 15) 

# open the text file in read mode 
f = open("myfile.txt", "r") 

# insert the texts in pdf 
for x in f: 
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = x, ln = 1, align = 'C') 

# save the pdf with name .pdf 
pdf.output("mygfg.pdf")
```

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is so low so I can't comment, but did you actually import the module in the py script? If not, maybe try throwing

> from FPDF import *

or

> from fpdf import FPDF

Answer (score 0):

**Did you import the module before using it?**

When you access the [Documentation](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you can see you must import the module before using it. Make sure you wrote this code before the others:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
```

The next code is an example available in the official PyFPDF documentation. Click [here](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/index.html) to access it.

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Hello World!')
pdf.output('tuto1.pdf', 'F')
```